# Simple Regex Expression - How to re-shape a url

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking to take a url that looks like:

```
http://www.example.com/activated-alumina-desiccant/t101c5.aspx
```

And change it to this:

```
http://www.example.com/Default.aspx?t=101&c=5
```

I would also like the flexibility to add other querystring variables, like:

```
http://www.example.com/activated-alumina-desiccant/t101c5p232.aspx
```

which would get me:

```
http://www.example.com/Default.aspx?t=101&c=5&p=232
```

So far I have the beginnings of what I need, `[^/]+$`

Which gets me the last part of the url, but beyond that, how do I break down the last bit and seperate ino querystring variables?  I am stumped!

Here is where the regex will go:
[image]

Comment: Why use regex? Is this a hard constraint?

Comment: I have to use RegEx as this is for a rewrite rule in web.config

Comment: @box86rowh Can it be _several_ regexes, or only one?

Comment: I think it has to be 1, I have posted an example image of where it will be setup in the system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex will split up a URL with up to 3 querystring variables:

`([^/]+//+[^/]+/)[^/]+/(\w)?(\d+)?(\w)?(\d+)?(\w)?(\d+)?\.aspx`

Use this for the replacement string:

`"$1Default.aspx?$2=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7"`

**EDIT:**

If trailing `&=`, eg, `http://www.example.com/Default.aspx?t=101&=&=`, don't cause a problem, you can get away with one regex, set to convert the maximum number of querystring variables expected. This maximum is limited by how many capturing groups are allowed by the regex engine in the replacement string (9 capturing groups gives an absolute max of 4, 99 gives an absolute max of 49).

If trailing `&=` *are* a problem you need to enter a regex for every different number of querystring variables expected. With this in mind the regex must be modified slightly (2-querystring example):

regex: `([^/]+//+[^/]+/)[^/]+/(\w)(\d+)(\w)(\d+)\.aspx`
replacement: `"$1Default.aspx?$2=$3&$4=$5"`

Comment: I doubt that there's a better way than to have this for three-variable queries, a similar one for two variables, another for four, etc...

Comment: Ill give this a shot when I get back to the desk.

Comment: @box86rowh - see my updated answer for a possible problem and the solution to it.

Comment: @box86rowh - No problemo. Just curious - did you use the solitary regex? If so do trailing `&=` cause problems?

Comment: I am able to use the solitary regex, the extra unused params make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Beginner C# code.

Ideone [Demo](http://ideone.com/f2csuP)

```
  string s="t101c5p2";
  string[]arr= Regex.Split(s,"(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z])");
  foreach(String str in arr)
  {
    string replaceStr = new Regex("([a-z])([0-9])").Replace(str,"$1=$2");
    Console.WriteLine(replaceStr);
  }
```

Output:

```
t=101
c=5
p=2
```

Comment: Request help in converting the same to C# and complete the answer instead of down voting.

Comment: Help request answered: use the [`Regex.Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx) for the regex part and [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6(VS.80).aspx) to loop over the result

Answer (score 0):

```
string url = "http://www.example.com/activated-alumina/t101c5p232.aspx";
var segment = new Uri(url).Segments.Last();
var parameters = 
      String.Join("&", Regex.Matches(segment, @"([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)")
                            .OfType<Match>()
                            .Select(m => m.Groups[1] + "=" + m.Groups[2]));

string result = "http://www.example.com/Default.aspx?" + parameters;
// http://www.example.com/Default.aspx?t=101&c=5&p=232
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/7uZlGy)